# What's the difference between using System.speech.recognition and ISpRecognizer in SAPI?

Tags: c#, .net, speech-recognition, sapi

I'm creating a simple speech recognition application and could implement recognition using the system.speech.recognition namespace. I came across ISpRecognizer in MSDN and would like to know how I can use it and other classes to improve my application.

Note: I need to prioritize user defined grammars and dictation grammar in my application as well

Comment: What have you tried so far, what is the problem you are running into. What needs to be improved. Your question needs to be more specific and should include a code sample. In an unrelated note, I may be mistaken, but I believe that System.Speech.Recognition is the .Net interface into the same speech API as ISpRecognizer. ISpRecognizer is the COM interface for the API.

Comment: @pstrjds I am using multiple grammars (grammar I defined and dictation grammar) and want to give more precedence to user-defined grammar than dictation grammar so that the recognizer will first check in user defined grammar(I can't find a better name to call it) before looking into dictation grammar

Comment: From your comment it sounds like your real questions is "How do I manage multiple Grammars in my speech recognition application". Is that what you are asking. The question you have posted sounds more like - How do I write an application using `System.Speech.Recognition` and/or `ISpRecognizer`" And that question doesn't line up with your title. Please clarify what you are stuck on. Some sample code of where you are stuck would aid others in answering.